# Improve performance of SO/SF/SU flair

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flair, performance

I have the flair from the three sites (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User) on my site. I have been doing some performance optimisations of my website and the flair are being identified by YSlow as causing performance issues:

- Each button has its own CSS file; could they not be combined into a single one?
- Minify the three CSS files (YSlow gives a C grade for this)
- Compress the three CSS files with gzip (YSlow gives a D grade for this)

Comment: Voting to close as too localized because flair is no longer made of HTML.

Comment: Well, @Popular, it's [no longer advertised](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/131713.html)...

Comment: @PopularDemand I really do not get what you are up to here. First it isn't too localised, it affected the entire of SO. That is the reverse of too localised. So mostly it would be historic and too time specific, as it is "status-completed" what benefit is there to close it now? it was asked over two years ago and the work was done. Closing it now, brings in no value for anyone.

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the CSS you could just move the tags into your own CSS file and use the unthemed version of the Flair. I used to do this for my own blog before I changed it and it can now use the standard flair.

I do like the idea of having a single file and choosing which flair to display.

**Update**

SE now offers Image Based Flair. Read more on the blog [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/)

Comment: I like this simpler idea much more than @Andrew's, most likely what I will implement to solve myself. I would like to see this fixed regardless for some users (thinking of SuperUser members) it may be beyond their skill and so if fixing it centrally benefits them too.

Answer (score 2):

YSlow isn't the law.

If you really want to improve performance, don't use the `<iframe>` or js iteration of the flair. You are uselessly initiating a request client-side to fetch external resources. Of course it will be costly!

Use the JSON format, parse it server side, and output your Stack Overflow information the way you want it on your blog.

Comment: Agree yslow isn't law, but it is a simple enough tool to find issues. The JSON format is a solution. However it is the complicated solution, maybe not for StackOverflow people but for ServerFault and SuperUser it may be beyond there skill level. Fixing it here benefits those with less skill than your solution requires.